# How to query collection using generic query builder

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am using the mongocsharpdriver nuget package (version 1.11.0) to run queries against a mongo database.

When creating a query object in c# I can do this:

```
var query = Query.EQ("RootValue", "foo");
```

I can use the nicer generic query Builders instead to do this:

```
var query = Query<RootObject>.EQ(x=>x.RootValue, "foo");
```

Now consider this query::

```
var query = Query.EQ("Things.Value", "bar");
```

Here `Things` is a collection of objects that have a string (`Value`) on them. In this case the query will return any object which has a match in any of the Values of Things.

**How do I write this query using the generic Query builder?**

I can't work out what expression I need that will get correctly translated to what I want...

In case it makes it clearer here are the classes for my example:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<RepeatedObject> Things {get; set;}
    public string RootValue {get; set;}
}

public class RepeatedObject
{
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Based on the version you mentioned you seem to be using the pretty dead legacy driver. May I suggest an upgrade? https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/

Comment: @dnickless: Yeah, I know its an old version (which is why i quoted the version). You know what its like finding time to upgrade - it works now so why spend the time? :) I may see if I can get it onto our dev schedule again though. Especially if it can do this better. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this version of the driver, the following query

```
var query = Query<RootObject>.ElemMatch(x => x.Things, x => x.EQ(y => y.Value, "bar"));
```

will be translated into the desired MongoDB query:

```
{ Things: { $elemMatch: { Value: "bar" } } }
```

Comment: Cool. I was expecting something like `{ "Things.Value" : "bar" }` but apparently that is equivalent to what you have (according to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition ). I assume it will treat them exactly the same.